# Kafka console producer skipping messages

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to send a file to a topic using:

```
cat myfile | kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list $BROKER_URL --topic mytopic
```

When I check the count of messages on the topic I see few hundred messages less than actual.

During the write I see a message:

```
[2017-11-15 14:05:26,864] WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 0 : {abc123=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

I have correctly set the advertised hostname and listeners.

What confuses me is that if leader is not available how does it manage to put any messages into the topic? Furthermore, the message appears randomly, sometimes it doesn't.

How can I debug this?

Comment: Is it possible you're hitting [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3129)?

Comment: `LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE` will always be returned to client to trigger the metadata update for an auto-created topic. So a transient occurrence does not matter. As for `message appears randomly`, I guess your topic has multiple partitions, so the messages go to different partitions, failing to provide global ordering when consuming. Rerun the test with single-partition topic.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. That is indeed the issue. The JIRA says that default ack for console producer has been changed to 1. Weird that its is still 0 for me, though I have the latest version of Kafka. Manually setting it to 1 fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by **vahid** in comments this is a know [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3129).

The workaround is to specify `--request-required-acks 1` to the console producer.

The random occurence of `LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE` happens when I write to a new topic without explicitly creating it first. (Thanks to **amethystic**)